Variance ratio when including irrelevant variables in a regression model
I am interested to know if there is a general formula for the ratio of the variance of regression coefficient for a predictor in a correctly specified model and a misspecified model.
Specifically, let's say we have a set of variables which really are relevant to the regression X and a set of variables which aren't relevant Y, and we do two regressions.
First, we do a weighted least squares regression of the form $y = X\beta_1$, which is correct and gives a coefficient estimate of $\hat{\beta_1}$.
Then, we do a weighted least squares regression of the form $y = X\beta_1 + Y\beta_2$, which is correct and gives a coefficient estimate of $\tilde{\beta_1}$.
I am interested in describing the ratio $var(\hat{\beta_1}) / var(\tilde{\beta_1})$ in closed form.
For ordinary unweighted linear regression, Fomby showed in LOSS OF EFFICIENCY IN REGRESSION ANALYSIS DUE TO
IRRELEVANT VARIABLES that there is a closed form for the ratio of the variances in the two models in terms of the canonical correlations between the predictors $r_i$ as $var(\hat{\beta_1}) / var(\tilde{\beta_1}) = \prod_i \frac{1}{1 - r_i^2}$.
Is there a clean generalization of this to the case of weighted least squares?
